# Точка входа python'a

Tags: python

Добрый день!

Я знаю, что в C# метод Main является точкой входа, и когда я, например, пошагова выполняю программу, то все начинается с метода Main, хотелось бы узнать, где точка входа у Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Python нет ничего похожего на main. Начало запускаемого модуля и есть точка входа.

Answer (score 7):

Обычно делают так:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # здесь код, который должен исполняться при запуске программы напрямую
```

Делают именно так по той причине, что если файл используется в качестве модуля, то никаких вычислений там совершать при импорте не нужно. А делать это нужно только при прямом запуске.

Comment: Если ты напишешь это в неосновном модуле, то этот кусок кода будет проигнорирован, и, соответственно, точкой входа его назвать уже не получится.

Answer (score 3):

Точка входа - это первая строка скрипта.

Если в Файле просто объявлен класс и не создается его экземпляр (и не вызываются методы) -  никакой полезной работы не будет выполнено.

Comment: А скриптов бывает много... Первая строка какого скрипта?

Comment: @flau того, который запускается. КО.